# TYPO3 set fe_user group

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 version 7.6.18. I trying create user by code. How to add user group? I see it need create user group object.

```
$this->objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
            $newUser = $this->objectManager->get('Fhk\\Feusersplus\\Domain\\Repository\\UserRepository');

$userModel = $this->objectManager>get('Fhk\\Feusersplus\\Domain\\Model\\User');

$userGroup = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();

$userModel->setUsername("sdfdsfdsfs");
$userModel->setEmail($user_data['email']);
$gender = 0;
$password = rand(99999999,9999999999999);
$userModel->setPassword($password);

$userModel->setUsergroup($userGroup);
$newUser->add($userModel);
```

I think the user did't add to database because I did't set user group. Help me please)

I have corrected my code but it does't add user to database:

```
 $this->objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
            $newUser = $this->objectManager->get('Fhk\\Feusersplus\\Domain\\Repository\\UserRepository');

                $userModel = $this->objectManager->get('Fhk\\Feusersplus\\Domain\\Model\\User');
                $userGroup = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Domain\\Repository\\FrontendUserGroupRepository');

                $userGroup = $userGroup->findByUid(1);
                $newUserGroup = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
                $newUserGroup->attach($userGroup);

            $userModel->setUsername("sdfdsfdsfs");
                $userModel->setEmail($user_data['email']);
                $gender = 0;
                $password = rand(99999999,9999999999999);
                $userModel->setPassword($password);
                $userModel->setPid(3);
                $userModel->setUsergroup($newUserGroup);

                $newUser->add($userModel);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are almost done. You need a `UserGroupRepository` to retrieve the user group you need and do `$userGroup->attach($yourUserGroup)`.

Comment: thank, seems that group I added. But user does't adding to database, I updated my post. can you help me please ?

Comment: Created and modified Extbase Objects are only transient. If you're not inside an createAction() or updateAction(), you have to take care of persisting the changes manually. You basically need an instance of \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager invoke the persistAll() method.

Answer (score 2):

try something like below.

```
$this->objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
$newUser = $this->objectManager->get('Fhk\\Feusersplus\\Domain\\Repository\\UserRepository');

$userModel = $this->objectManager->get('Fhk\\Feusersplus\\Domain\\Model\\User');
$userGroup = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Domain\\Repository\\FrontendUserGroupRepository');

$userGroup = $this->FrontendUserGroupRepository->findByUid(1);

$userModel = new \Typo3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser();

$userModel->setUsername("sdfdsfdsfs");
$userModel->setEmail($user_data['email']);
$gender = 0;
$password = rand(99999999,9999999999999);
$userModel->setPassword($password);
$userModel->setPid(3);
$userModel->addUsergroup($userGroup);

$this->FrontendUserRepository->add($userModel);
```